# Assembly 8086 - push and mov

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am learning for my exam and I can't understand why those two operations are wrong:

1. `mov al, 0110h`
2. `push dh`

and this is right:

1. `push si`

What exactly I can push on stack?

Comment: 1) `0110h` is bigger than 8 bits, it obviously doesn't fit into `al` which is a 8 bit register.  2) you can only push 16 bit registers

Comment: thank you. I have one question to the second answer : shouldn't it be bigger or equal to 16bit registers , because I think that push eax is possible, which is 32bit register

Comment: If `push eax` is possible depends on the instruction set/current processor mode. If it is 32-bit, then it would be ok. `push dh` seems to be invalid, see [PUSH](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html). Although `push imm8` is valid, `push r/m8` ("push dh") is not. So stack alignment seems to be of no concern. `push r/m16` ("push si") is valid, as you can see.

Comment: You put `8086` in the title. That has no `eax`.

Comment: @zx485 You can also do a `push eax` in 16 bit mode—in this case, the assembler inserts a 66h prefix before the instruction to indicate that it's a 32 bit push.

Comment: @FUZxxl: You're right. Anyone who is interested in the specifics can visit [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14660027/1305969)